# Create functions in Python NLTK to get information retrieval

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, information-retrieval

I am a beginner in using Python NLTK to create inverted index to get information retrieval.

The function *makeInvertedIndex* which I successfully created is to take a dict variable rdes_list as input, the output is an inverted index dictionary.
For example:

> input rdes_list = {1:'hello world',2:'hello',3:'hello cat',4:'hellolot of cats'}
>
> output index_dict = {'hello': [0, 1, 2], 'cat': [2], 'of': [3], 'world': [0], 'cats': [3], 'hellolot': [3]}

Based on the above function, I meet the problem to create other two functions:
The first one is to create a *orSearch* (invertedIndex, query)function, which takes an inverted index (i.e., index_dict) and query (i.e., a list of words), then returns the set of document numbers specifying all documents that contain **any** of the words in query.

The second one is to create a *andSearch* (invertedIndex, query)function, which takes an inverted index (i.e., index_dict) and query (i.e., a list of words), then returns the set of document numbers specifying all documents that contain **all** of the words in query.

Answer (score 0):

I offer the following solution:

```
output_index_dict = {'hello': [0, 1, 2], 'cat': [2], 'of': [3], 'world': [0], 'cats': [3], 'hellolot': [3]}

def orSearch (invertedIndex, query):
    result = []
    for key, value in invertedIndex.items():
        if key in query:
            result.append(value)
    relevant_documents = [index for indexes in result for index in indexes]
    return set(relevant_documents)

>>> orSearch(output_index_dict, ['of', 'hello', 'cat'])
output : {0, 1, 2, 3}

def andSearch (invertedIndex, query):
    result = []
    for key, value in invertedIndex.items():
        if key in query:
            result.append(value)
    common_indexes = set.intersection(*map(set,result))
    return common_indexes

>>> andSearch(output_index_dict, ['hellolot', 'of', 'cats'])
output : {3}
```

Hope I did not miss something in your request.

Comment: This looks very helpful. However, we try to encourage contributors to explain why their solution would work, or what problem it is solving. This helps other readers learn from the answers offered. Can you add a sentence or two to your post?

Comment: @Elliot. Thank you so much. However, you code doesn't actually solve the problem. The error reported by the traceback says that the tuple which means key, value do not have the attribute items().

Comment: what python version do you use ?